# Trying to change modifier properties through script

Tags: modifiers

There are plenty of questions on here asking how to add a new modifier to an object or objects. I am looking to change the properties of an existing modifier on an object. The following text is what I have came up with as an attempt that has failed.

```py
import bpy

obj =  bpy.context.object

modifier = obj.modifier(name="Array", type='ARRAY')

modifier.constant_offset_displace[0] = 1.6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of existing modifiers from `obj.modifiers`.
You can access them by index or by name. For example, if the array modifier you want is the first in the stack and called "Array", you can get with either of these:

- `modifier = obj.modifiers[0]`
- `modifier = obj.modifiers["Array"]`

From there on you can set the properties as you see them in the Python tooltips or in the auto completion of the Python console (or the API reference).

One correct solution for the code of your example would be:

```
import bpy

obj =  bpy.context.object
modifier = obj.modifiers["Array"] # Get existing modifier with name "Array"
modifier.constant_offset_displace[0] = 1.6
```

Note that the user can change a modifier's name at any time, so you might want to use a more stable way of finding the modifier, but what's the best way to do that depends on your specific case.

Comment: Recommend avoiding keyerrors with `m = ob.modifiers.get("Array")` which if there is no modifier of that name will be `None`. Or by type `array_mods = [m for m in ob.modifers if m.type == 'ARRAY']` for  a list of all array modifiers on the object.

Comment: Thank you, just need to find a way of making it so that if the value is "1.6" then change it to "-1.6" and if it's "-1.6" change it back to "1.6"

Comment: @JackKerry That's a bit out of the scope of the question. But why don't you just multiply it with -1? `modifier.constant_offset_displace[0] *= -1`